# Ansible known_hosts module with a loop

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run a task executing the `known_hosts` module with a list of key entries. The problem is that I keep getting the following error, even though the variable has data when using `debug`.

```
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined
```

I have the following task which registers a variable of the ssh-keyscan output

```
- name: keyscan platform hosts
  shell: "ssh-keyscan ssh.{{ item }}"
  register: "platform_ssh_host_keys"
  loop:
    - "one.example.com"
    - "two.example.com"
```

When I run the following debug, I get the stdout which contains the key

```
- name: debug
  debug:
    var: item.stdout
  with_items: "{{platform_ssh_host_keys.results}}"
```

But as soon as I run it with `known_hosts` it says `item` is undefined.

```
- name: configure known_hosts
  known_hosts:
    path: "~/.ssh/known_hosts"
    name: "ssh.{{ item.item }}"
    key: "{{ item.stdout }}"
    state: present
    loop: "{{ platform_ssh_host_keys.results }}"
```

I don't get how `item` can be defined in `debug` but not `known_hosts` task.

Answer (score 2):

‍♂️ Well, after I posted this I immediately realized the problem was due to the fact I had `loop` as a property for `known_hosts` and not the tasks. So the problem was indentation.

This fixed it all.

```
- name: configure known_hosts
  known_hosts:
    path: "~/.ssh/known_hosts"
    name: "ssh.{{ item.item }}"
    key: "{{ item.stdout }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{platform_ssh_host_keys.results}}"
```